# EnableAutoConfiguration generates unnecessary CGLIB proxies of repositories

Tags: spring-boot

Before Spring Boot 1.2 everything used to work fine, however with this version the @EnableAutoConfiguration tag causes the generation of CGLIB proxies of the JDBC repositories. Since these repository classes are marked final, it fails. I have no problem with making these classes non-final, however I'd like to understand why CGLIB proxies are needed in this case. However if I remove the EnableAutoConfiguration tag, everything works as expected, i.e., no CGLIB proxies are created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.2 added auto-configuration for Spring's persistence exception translation which requires the use of proxies. You can disable it by setting `spring.dao.exceptiontranslation.enabled: false` in your `application.properties` file.

Comment: I thought the DataAccessException hierarchy was automatically used by Spring? I only have JDBC implementations.

Comment: The exception translation's applied to any bean that's annotated with @Repository which, I'm guessing, your JDBC-based repositories must be.